# Balance in SQL Server query by month by account

Tags: sql-server

I need to build a query to get all the account's monthly balances between Jan/2020 and Dec/2020.

Basically I need this:

```
Account_id| Year  | Jan |Feb| Mar| Apr|May | Jun| Jul| Aug|Sep| Oct| Nov|Dec
---------  ----  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
        1 | 2020  | 200 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 0 |-500| 400| 0
        2 | 2020  |  0  | 0 |  0 | 500|  0 |  0 | 900|  0 | 0 | 100| 0  | 0
        3 | 2020  | 100 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 0  |  0 | 0 | 200| 500| 0
```

Sample data:

Table `Accounts`:

```
account_id| customer_id|.....
---------  ----  --- --- --
        1 |   x1       |......
        2 |   x2       |.....
```

Table `Transfer_ins`:

```
id  | account_id|amount
---------  ----  --- -
xx  |      1 |   100      
xx  |      2 |   300
```

Table `Transfer_outs`:

```
id  | account_id|amount
---------  ----  --- --
 xx |      1    |   100      
 xx |      2    |   300
```

Table `Transfer_ins`:

```
id  | account_id|    amount|
---------  ----  --- --- --
 yy |      1    |   100    | 
 yy |      2    |   300    |
```

Table `d_month`:

```
id| month_id|action_month|
---------  ----  --- --- --
x1|      1  |   january  |
x4       2  |   february |
```

Table `pix_movements`:

```
id  |account_id|   in_or_out    |pix_amount
---------  ----  --- --- --   ----
 yy |      1   |   pix_out      | 300
 yy |      2   |   pix_in       | 900
```

Table `d_time`:

```
time_id|action_stamp            |   week_id |   month_id |year_id
---------  ----  --- --- --   ------------------------
 uu    |2020-01-04T15:00:55.960Z|   zz      |     yy     | xx
 uu    |2020-01-04T15:00:55.960Z|   zz      |     yy     | xx
```

This is what I wrote:

```
SELECT
    account_id, action_month,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 1 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 1 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 1 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 1 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Jan
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 2 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 2 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 2 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 2 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Feb
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 3 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 3 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 3 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 3 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Mar
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 4 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 4 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 4 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 4 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Apr
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 5 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 5 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 5 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 5 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) May
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 6 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 6 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 6 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 6 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Jun
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 7 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 7 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 7 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 7 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Jul
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 8 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 8 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 8 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 8 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Aug
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 9 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 9 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 9 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 9 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Sep
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 10 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 10 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 10 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 10 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Oct
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 11 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 11 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 11 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 11 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Nov 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 11 THEN transfer_ins.amount END)+SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 12 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_in" THEN pix.movements.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 12 THEN transfer_outs.amount END)-SUM(CASE WHEN month(action_month) = 12 AND pix_movements.in_or_out = "pix_out" THEN pix.movements.amount END), 0) Dic 
FROM
    accounts
INNER JOIN
    pix_movemets ON accounts.account_id = pix_movements.account_id
INNER JOIN
    transfer_outs ON accounts.account_id = transfer_outs.account_id
INNER JOIN
    transfer_ins ON accounts.account_id = transfer_ins.account_id
GROUP BY
    account_id
```

But I keep getting errors, I don't know how to do it.

I understand that I need to SUM the amount of the transfer_ins.amount + pix_movements.pix_amount where = pix_movements.in_or_out = "in". The result of each month I need to subtract with transfer_outs.amount + pix_movements.pix_amount where = pix.movements.in_or_out = "out" by account.

The tables are in the image below. I think that I need to use the tables: transfer_ins transfer_outs accounts pix_movements d_time d_year

Schema-Entity:

[image: Schema-Entity]

Comment: So if this is to run in SQLServer, WHY did you tag MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, I've already delete the Tag

Comment: "I keep getting errors" what errors? Sample tables and data would help, we cannot run your query without that

Comment: I added some sample tables that might help